# How is my isolation transformer not short circuited?

Tags: transformer, three-phase, isolation

I received a 3 phase 240 to 208 isolation transformer, and I am unsure how the current configuration (as it was shipped to me) would not cause a short circuit. When I do an ohms reading on the high and low side bars I get the following:

- H1 <-> H2: 0.3Ω
- H2 <-> H3: 0.3Ω
- H1 <-> H3: 0.3Ω
- x1 <-> x2: 0.2Ω
- x2 <-> x3: 0.4Ω
- x1 <-> x3: 0.2Ω
- Hn <-> xN: open circuit (which I would expect)

My assumption is that I need to connect:

- 240Vac Delta L1(in) to H1, L2(in) to H2 and L3(in) to H3.
- 208Vac Delta X1 to L1(out), X2 to L2(out), and X3 to L3(out).

However, **my concern is that on either high or low side there would be a current of**:

- between H nodes:  800 Amps = 240Vac / 0.3Ω
- between X nodes: 1040 Amps = 208Vac / 0.2Ω

**What am I missing?**

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of project you are taking on? With 3-phase 240V lines it is deadly dangerous. I would suggest either follow up an application diagram to the letter, or hire a qualified electrician to do the job.

Comment: @Ale..chenski dangerous indeed. The photo clearly and correctly shows a big red warning label. But no, we just go on playing with it, even without knowing much about electrical engineering :-(

Comment: @Roland sure but at some point, even a professional had a first time.

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring the DC resistance of the coils. When an AC voltage is applied, the *reactance* of the coils will oppose the current and limit the power draw to a few dozen watts, according to [Hammond's datasheet](https://documents.hammondpowersolutions.com/documents/Product%20Info/Distribution_Transformers/Encapsulated_Transformers/Sentinel_G/HPS_Sentinel_G_Typical_Performance_150_Rise.pdf).  There still will be [inrush current](https://documents.hammondpowersolutions.com/documents/Product%20Info/Distribution_Transformers/Encapsulated_Transformers/Sentinel_G/HPS_Sentinel_G_Single_Phase_Typical_Impedance_and_Inrush_Current_Range.pdf) but that is transient.

Comment: Thank you Vir, just prior to you posting this I realized my error in thinking. I was thinking there was conductivity caused by each lead being connected to the red bar. Now it makes more sense that my DMM was slow to find an ohms reading...

Comment: @JCoder, this is not a matter of DMM being slow or else. BTW, with inductors of that size even operating a DMM in ohmmeter mode might give you a serious electric shock upon probe disconnects. I would strongly suggest to stop what you are doing.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I appreciate the concern and feedback, but everyone has to start somewhere. You need to research, ask questions, and realize you may not know something, but you still have to try new things. If not, you never learn anything new. I would argue that is the point of stack exchange. This is a "network (to) help people find the answers they need, when they need them." Learning to eat solid food was dangerous for everyone at one point.

Comment: @JCoder,  "everyone has to start somewhere" -  I don't disagree. But please don't start with 240V and AWG10 wires, start with something smaller, with small batteries or something.

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring 0.2Ω or 0.3Ω of resistance using DC current supplied by your ohmmeter. You would indeed have hundreds of amps flowing if you applied 200V DC across those terminals. The reason that doesn't happen is two-fold:

1. The applied mains voltage isn't DC, it's AC, swapping polarity 100 or 120 times each second.
2. The coils are actually inductors, with inductance.

Inductance is a kind of resistance to *changing* current. That is, current might initially try to rise sharply, but inductance prevents that. Given time to do so, current would eventually rise to the values you mention, but that time *isn't* given. Before current has a chance to rise in either direction, the voltage across the inductor swaps polarity, and the slow rise in current is halted.